# Wordnet database has letters in weird/invalid places

Tags: nlp, text-processing, wordnet

I was noticing that some lines in the [database files](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html) (like data.verb) are not following the correct format. (The database format is [outlined here](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html)).

```
02286687 40 v 0a fall_upon d strike 0 come_upon 9 light_upon 0 chance_upon 0 come_across 2 chance_on 0 happen_upon 0 attain d discover 0 003 @ 02285629 v 0000 + 07214432 n 0a01 + 00043195 n 0a01 01 + 08 00 | find unexpectedly; "the archeologists chanced upon an old tomb"; "she struck a goldmine"; "The hikers finally struck the main path to the lake"
```

Where the w_cnt **0a** should be a the number 10. This also happens in other places like:

```
02575723 41 v 08 flim-flam 0 play_a_joke_on 1 play_tricks 0 trick 0 fob 0 fox 0 pull_a_fast_one_on 0 play_a_trick_on 0 008 @ 02575082 v 0000 + 10022759 n 0602 + 00171618 n 0401 + 10463714 n 0404 + 06760722 n 0401 + 00752954 n 0401 + 00779248 n 010c ~ 02578384 v 0000 02 + 09 00 + 30 04 | deceive somebody; "We tricked the teacher into thinking that class would be cancelled next week"
```

Where **010c** isn't a valid number. Unless [digit][letter] is a valid format, *but is not described in the documentation I have read so far*.

Why are their random letters among the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the numbers are in [hexadecimal format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) - A is 10, for example.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Well 010c is actually two numbers according to the docs (weird there are no spaces) so "0c" must mean "12".